# How to retype the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

[image]

I hope, users can type text directly into the combobox.
And then when the dropdown button is clicked, a Form will appear(instead of the usual dropdown menu.)
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to create your own custom column, cell and editing control to make it worthwhile. You can handle the `EditingControlShowing` event of the grid and configure the `ComboBox` editing control to allow entering arbitrary text by setting the `DropDownStyle` property to `DropDown` instead of `DropDownList`, but it will do you little good. That's because, the way the standard column works, the `Value` of the cell is copied to the `SelectedValue` of the editing control when you start editing a cell and then back again when you finish. As it stands, any text you enter would simply be ignored. Your custom cell and editing control would have to handle the fact that an item from the drop-down list may or may not be selected and your custom column would have to use the custom cell as its template. It's doable but it's far from trivial. If you're up for the challenge then you had better start researching custom `DataGridView` columns and how to create them.

Comment: Please help me when the dropdown button is clicked, a Form will appear (Instead of the usual dropdown menu.) Sorry...

Comment: @ArthurChen, it sounds like you shouldn't be using a `ComboBox` column at all. A custom column with a `TextBox` and a `Button` would be far more appropriate. The whole point of a `ComboBox` column is to select an item from a drop-down list. You want to do two things that aren't that so don't use that column type. Use an appropriate tool for the job.